# VBA unable to execute code

Tags: vba, excel, recordset

My problem is that, whatever I typed in the textbox, it will only execute `MsgBox ("Estimate No" & editform.edittext.Value & " is found")` even though the record does not exist in the database. It should execute the code
`MsgBox ("Unable to find '" & editform.edittext.Value & "'")` when record is not found in database.

```
If editform.OptionButton1.Value = True Then
    strConnectStr = "something"
    Qry = "SELECT * " & _
          "FROM test.dbo.estimateRegister " & _
          "WHERE test.dbo.estimateRegister.estimateNo = '" & edittext.Text & "%'"

    cnt.Open strConnectStr
    rst.Open Qry, cnt

    If Not rst.EOF Then
        MsgBox ("Estimate No" & editform.edittext.Value & " is found")
        Unload Me
        UserForm2.Show
    Else
        MsgBox ("Unable to find '" & editform.edittext.Value & "'")
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Try to remove braces... just MsgBox "Message"

Comment: It has no difference. I tried it.

Comment: Have you `On Error Resume Next` somewhere in your code before the `If Not rst.EOF Then ...`? If so then `rst` maybe `Nothing` or another object which has no `.EOF` at this point.

Comment: nope. I do not have any of that code

Comment: So what kind of object is `rst` at the point? Have you tried to debug in single step mode and have a look at `rst` in local window? Or assign `rst.RecordCount` to a variable and watch this variable? Maybe there are record sets though?

Comment: I do have recordset on some other forms, does it affect in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line:

```
If Not rst.EOF Then
```

with this line

```
If rst.RecordCount <> 0 Then
```

Comment: @Reeve What happens then? Do you get error? Can you be more specific in `It Doesn't work`?

Comment: Still the same thing as before

Comment: @Reeve Strange cause it works in my end. Btw, your first code works as well.

Comment: thats strange, let me work it out, i will get back to you in awhile.